# how do I modify this trigger to solve mutating-table error?

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to setup a trigger to insert the payment_date on a new invoice. Here is my original trigger which I thought would work fine but is receiving the mutating-table error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER payment_before_insert_invoice
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON invoices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE invoices set payment_date = get_paymentdate(invoice_date);
END;
```

The get_paymentdate function simply returns a payment_date based off invoice_date + term.

I read about solving the mutating-table problem by using a compound trigger but do not fully understand it....here is what I have but I am receiving errors. Would anyone be able to help with this please? I'm understanding in theory, it is supposed to put the data into a temp table using an array but kind of lost as you can see below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER payment_before_insert_invoice
FOR UPDATE OF payment_date
ON invoices
COMPOUND TRIGGER
TYPE invoice_date_table IS TABLE OF DATE;
TYPE payment_date_table IS TABLE OF DATE;
TYPE ids_totals_table INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

invoice_dates  invoice_ids_table;
payment_dates payment_date_table;
ids_totals  ids_totals_table;

BEFORE STATEMENT IS
invoice_date DATE
payment_date DATE;
BEGIN
SELECT invoice_id, payment_date
BULK COLLECT INTO invoice_dates, payment_dates
FROM invoices;

FOR i IN 1...invoice_dates.COUNT() LOOP
invoice_date := invoice_dates(i);
payment_date := payment_dates(i);
ids_totals(invoice_date) := payment_dates;
END LOOP;
END BEFORE STATEMENT;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
payment_date DATE;
BEGIN
UPDATE invoices set payment_date = get_paymentdate(invoice_date);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have several issues in your original trigger.  First, your UPDATE statement is attempting to change EVERY row in the INVOICES table.  You have no constraint on it.  Even then it won't work.  If you simply want to calculate a value for one of the fields, change it to a BEFORE trigger, and assign the function value to the column of interest using the :new pseudo reference:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER payment_before_insert_invoice
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON invoices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :new.payment_date = get_paymentdate(:new.invoice_date);
END;
```